# IMAP files trashed and greyed out - can't recover in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

A few days ago, my IMAP files were sent to the trash (if I did it, it was by accident, but I really don't remember doing it...) So the main file is there in the trash but I cannot scroll down the files, and its greyed out. And also I cannot recover the files, or put them back on the inbox!! Any ideas?

Here's a picture of what it looks like!
Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i took away the IMAP prefix in settings : imap.secureserver.net
left it blank and now it works again.[image]